# Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb.frames

Tags: python, c++, c, linux, debugging

I am trying to do live debugging of a process on a embedded system running RHEL 7.6.1-80.e17.

When i try to attach to the live process, i get python exception.  I could find a similar question posted prev but couldn't understand.

Can some one explain clearly how to resolve the python exception?.

```
WN508002000158FFA0 # gdb /usr/bin/fp
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb:

warning:
Could not load the Python gdb module from `/usr/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.

GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-80.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/fp...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) attach 598


................
..............

Loaded symbols for /lib64/libdev.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libdev.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libdev1.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libdev1.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libdev2.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libdev2.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib64/libdev3.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib64/libdev3.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

(gdb) bt
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb.frames:
(gdb)
```

Comment: Sounds like you failed to install `gdb` correctly.

Comment: Latest is `gdb-7.6.1-100.el7` The module `frames.py` : `/usr/share/gdb/python/gdb/frames.py` ... Suggest : `# yum reinstall gdb`